VS Code 1.95 debugger for nodeJS stopped working
Debugger on VSCode for NodeJS stopped working today. It was working fine until late last week.
I couldn't directly upload the gif on StackOverflow (apparently the image is above the size limit) you can refer to the gif in the following link:
I recorded a short video (in .gif format) of what happens when I try to start debugging.  The video shows that when running debugger, it launches, the debug buttons show up for a moment then shuts down with no error messages.
I've upgraded my VSCode from 1.94.0 to 1.95.2 late last week so I tried reinstalling the old version (1.94.0) but the same issue occurs.
The node version I am using is v23.2.0 and npm version is 10.9.0.
I've tried turning on "trace": true in launch.json and couldn't find any major issues or reasons as to why debug didn't run:
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889683832,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"initialize","arguments":{"clientID":"vscode","clientName":"Visual Studio Code","adapterID":"pwa-node","pathFormat":"path","linesStartAt1":true,"columnsStartAt1":true,"supportsVariableType":true,"supportsVariablePaging":true,"supportsRunInTerminalRequest":true,"locale":"en","supportsProgressReporting":true,"supportsInvalidatedEvent":true,"supportsMemoryReferences":true,"supportsArgsCanBeInterpretedByShell":true,"supportsMemoryEvent":true,"supportsStartDebuggingRequest":true,"supportsANSIStyling":true},"type":"request","seq":1}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683832,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":1,"type":"response","request_seq":1,"command":"initialize","success":true,"body":{"supportsConfigurationDoneRequest":true,"supportsFunctionBreakpoints":false,"supportsConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsHitConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsEvaluateForHovers":true,"supportsReadMemoryRequest":true,"supportsWriteMemoryRequest":true,"exceptionBreakpointFilters":[{"filter":"all","label":"Caught Exceptions","default":false,"supportsCondition":true,"description":"Breaks on all throw errors, even if they're caught later.","conditionDescription":"error.name == \"MyError\""},{"filter":"uncaught","label":"Uncaught Exceptions","default":false,"supportsCondition":true,"description":"Breaks only on errors or promise rejections that are not handled.","conditionDescription":"error.name == \"MyError\""}],"supportsStepBack":false,"supportsSetVariable":true,"supportsRestartFrame":true,"supportsGotoTargetsRequest":false,"supportsStepInTargetsRequest":true,"supportsCompletionsRequest":true,"supportsModulesRequest":false,"additionalModuleColumns":[],"supportedChecksumAlgorithms":[],"supportsRestartRequest":true,"supportsExceptionOptions":false,"supportsValueFormattingOptions":true,"supportsExceptionInfoRequest":true,"supportTerminateDebuggee":true,"supportsDelayedStackTraceLoading":true,"supportsLoadedSourcesRequest":true,"supportsLogPoints":true,"supportsTerminateThreadsRequest":false,"supportsSetExpression":true,"supportsTerminateRequest":false,"completionTriggerCharacters":[".","[","\"","'"],"supportsBreakpointLocationsRequest":true,"supportsClipboardContext":true,"supportsExceptionFilterOptions":true,"supportsEvaluationOptions":false,"supportsDebuggerProperties":false,"supportsSetSymbolOptions":false,"supportsANSIStyling":true}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683836,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":2,"type":"event","event":"initialized","body":{}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889683840,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"launch","arguments":{"type":"pwa-node","name":"Launch Program","request":"launch","trace":{"stdio":true,"logFile":"c:\\Users\\dkim1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\logs\\20241118T132057\\window5\\exthost\\ms-vscode.js-debug\\vscode-debugadapter-6344ce95.json.gz"},"outputCapture":"console","timeout":10000,"timeouts":{},"showAsyncStacks":true,"skipFiles":["<node_internals>/**"],"smartStep":true,"sourceMaps":true,"sourceMapRenames":true,"pauseForSourceMap":false,"resolveSourceMapLocations":["C:\\Temp\\testapp/**/*.(m|c|)js","!**/node_modules/**"],"rootPath":"C:\\Temp\\testapp","outFiles":["C:\\Temp\\testapp/**/*.(m|c|)js","!**/node_modules/**"],"sourceMapPathOverrides":{"webpack:///./~/*":"c:\\Temp\\testapp/node_modules/*","webpack:////*":"/*","webpack://@?:*/?:*/*":"c:\\Temp\\testapp/*","webpack://?:*/*":"c:\\Temp\\testapp/*","webpack:///([a-z]):/(.+)":"$1:/$2","meteor://app/*":"c:\\Temp\\testapp/*","turbopack://[project]/*":"C:\\Temp\\testapp/*"},"enableContentValidation":true,"cascadeTerminateToConfigurations":[],"enableDWARF":true,"__workspaceFolder":"c:\\Temp\\testapp","__breakOnConditionalError":false,"cwd":"c:\\Temp\\testapp","env":{},"envFile":null,"localRoot":null,"remoteRoot":null,"autoAttachChildProcesses":true,"runtimeSourcemapPausePatterns":[],"program":"C:\\Temp\\testapp\\app.js","stopOnEntry":false,"console":"internalConsole","restart":false,"args":[],"runtimeExecutable":"node","runtimeVersion":"default","runtimeArgs":[],"profileStartup":false,"attachSimplePort":null,"experimentalNetworking":"auto","killBehavior":"forceful","__configurationTarget":6,"__workspaceCachePath":"c:\\Users\\dkim1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\03d089070aa5db2fbfa2943c367e5f14\\ms-vscode.js-debug","__sessionId":"18328475-2be9-474c-864f-9a638a80a8a6"},"type":"request","seq":2}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683840,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":3,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"js-debug/launch","data":{"type":"pwa-node","request":"launch","os":"win32 x64","nodeVersion":"v20.16.0","adapterVersion":"1.94.0","parameters":"{\"type\":\"pwa-node\",\"name\":\"<string>\",\"request\":\"launch\",\"trace\":{\"stdio\":true,\"logFile\":\"<string>\"},\"outputCapture\":\"console\",\"timeout\":10000,\"timeouts\":{},\"showAsyncStacks\":true,\"skipFiles\":[\"<string>\"],\"smartStep\":true,\"sourceMaps\":true,\"sourceMapRenames\":true,\"pauseForSourceMap\":false,\"resolveSourceMapLocations\":[\"<string>\",\"<string>\"],\"rootPath\":\"<string>\",\"outFiles\":[\"<string>\",\"<string>\"],\"sourceMapPathOverrides\":{\"webpack:///./~/*\":\"<string>\",\"webpack:////*\":\"<string>\",\"webpack://@?:*/?:*/*\":\"<string>\",\"webpack://?:*/*\":\"<string>\",\"webpack:///([a-z]):/(.+)\":\"<string>\",\"meteor://app/*\":\"<string>\",\"turbopack://[project]/*\":\"<string>\"},\"enableContentValidation\":true,\"cascadeTerminateToConfigurations\":[],\"enableDWARF\":true,\"__workspaceFolder\":\"<string>\",\"__breakOnConditionalError\":false,\"cwd\":\"<string>\",\"env\":{},\"envFile\":null,\"localRoot\":null,\"remoteRoot\":null,\"autoAttachChildProcesses\":true,\"runtimeSourcemapPausePatterns\":[],\"program\":\"<string>\",\"stopOnEntry\":false,\"console\":\"internalConsole\",\"restart\":false,\"args\":[],\"runtimeExecutable\":\"node\",\"runtimeVersion\":\"default\",\"runtimeArgs\":[],\"profileStartup\":false,\"attachSimplePort\":null,\"experimentalNetworking\":\"auto\",\"killBehavior\":\"forceful\",\"__configurationTarget\":6,\"__workspaceCachePath\":\"<string>\",\"__sessionId\":\"<string>\"}"}}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683841,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":4,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"Verbose logs are written to:\nc:\\Users\\dkim1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\logs\\20241118T132057\\window5\\exthost\\ms-vscode.js-debug\\vscode-debugadapter-6344ce95.json.gz\n"}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889683843,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"setBreakpoints","arguments":{"source":{"name":"app.js","path":"c:\\Temp\\testapp\\app.js"},"lines":[1],"breakpoints":[{"line":1}],"sourceModified":false},"type":"request","seq":3}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889683844,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"setExceptionBreakpoints","arguments":{"filters":[],"filterOptions":[]},"type":"request","seq":4}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683844,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":5,"type":"response","request_seq":3,"command":"setBreakpoints","success":true,"body":{"breakpoints":[{"id":1,"verified":false,"message":"Unbound breakpoint"}]}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683844,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":6,"type":"response","request_seq":4,"command":"setExceptionBreakpoints","success":true,"body":{}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889683859,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"configurationDone","type":"request","seq":5}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683859,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":7,"type":"response","request_seq":5,"command":"configurationDone","success":true,"body":{}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889683860,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"threads","type":"request","seq":6}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889683860,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":8,"type":"response","request_seq":6,"command":"threads","success":true,"body":{"threads":[]}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"runtime.launch","timestamp":1731889683923,"message":"Using binary at","metadata":{"location":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe","executable":"node"},"level":1}
{"tag":"runtime.launch","timestamp":1731889683972,"message":"Discovered version","metadata":{"version":"v23.2.0"},"level":1}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889684038,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":9,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe .\\app.js\n"}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"runtime.launch","timestamp":1731889684045,"message":"Launched successfully","metadata":{"name":"Yl"},"level":1}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889684045,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":10,"type":"response","request_seq":2,"command":"launch","success":true,"body":{}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889684084,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"breakpointLocations","arguments":{"source":{"name":"app.js","path":"c:\\Temp\\testapp\\app.js"},"line":1},"type":"request","seq":7}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889684084,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":11,"type":"response","request_seq":7,"command":"breakpointLocations","success":true,"body":{"breakpoints":[]}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889684160,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":12,"type":"event","event":"terminated","body":{"restart":false}}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.receive","timestamp":1731889684163,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"command":"disconnect","arguments":{"restart":false,"terminateDebuggee":false},"type":"request","seq":8}},"level":0}
{"tag":"dap.send","timestamp":1731889684163,"metadata":{"connectionId":6,"message":{"seq":13,"type":"response","request_seq":8,"command":"disconnect","success":true,"body":{}}},"level":0}

My launch.json file is as follows:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js",
            "trace": true
        }
    ]
}


Do you have a launch.json to share?  Is the program field pointing to the file you think it is?  Did the first console.log("hi") happen? (it seems not). Did you try code --disable-extensions? does node inspect app.js work (CLI debugger)?

Hi @Wyck, thanks for your message. I've shared my launch.json code in my post.
I just tried code --disable-extensions and ran debug with no luck. Same issue is occuring when trying to debug with no extensions.
I was able to run node inspect app.js
step in app.js:2
  1 console.log("hi");
> 2 console.log("welcome");
debug> n
< welcome
<
step in app.js:2
  1 console.log("hi");
> 2 console.log("welcome");
debug> n


have you set any breakpoints? does this occur in a minimal script?

Hi @starball, In the short video gif link, I do have a breakpoint in line 1 of C:\Temp\testapp\app.js. However it doesn't stop at that breakpoint and neither of the console.log messages in line 1 or line 2 shows up in the debug console. Thanks for your message.

It seems to be a bug in 23.2.0 and 23.3.0, it works fine on 23.1.0 for me.

Can confirm. I was running 23.3.0 and unable to hit any breakpoints. Downgrading to 23.1.0 did the trick

Thanks so much. I can confirm I was running 23.3.0 as well. I couldn't track down 23.1.0 so downgraded to v22.12.0 (LTS) and it works fine. Cheers.

To elaborate, VSCode debugger is not attaching with NodeJS 23.3.0. There is a ticket https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/235023
I've downgraded to NodeJS v22.12.0 (LTS) and it works. Cheers.
